# Oracle with ubuntu sqlplus command not found

Tags: python, django, oracle11g, django-rest-framework

i installed oracle 11.2g in my system
my system path is as follows :

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

i run the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

and i got output

```
Installation completed successfully.
```

now i tried

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba
```

and i got output

```
sqlplus: command not found
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Check if oracle bin directory is in your path by printing $PATH variable in console:

```
echo $PATH
```

You should find `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin` here.

If you installed oracle-xe with the same bash session where you're trying to execute `sqlplus` you should reload `.profile` (or another file with exported variables). You could do it with `source` command:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: thanks ...everything is working now....i run command django-admin.py syncdb i got err : django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener.

Comment: Check if oracle is running. I'm not sure about the name of the process but you could try to find something with 'ps aux | grep oracle'.

Comment: yes it is running......OUTPUT:- oracle    2570  0.0  0.3 218152 13640 ?        Ssl  13:58   0:00 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER -inherit

Comment: Okay, so at first try to connect with some db tool to make sure you've configured your python scripts properly. For example SQLDeveloper. Here's short info about connection parameters in case of Oracle-XE: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/howto-connect-xe-095131.html

Comment: SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Jul 3 15:06:24 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: emp137
Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select 2+2 from dual;

       2+2
----------
  4

SQL>